# redux returning the new state of App

Tags: reactjs, redux

I was going through this article of Medium by [cloudboost talking about redux](https://blog.cloudboost.io/beginners-guide-to-react-redux-painting-a-mental-model-ed0279d55836)

Here, Midway in the article, they wrote something like this

> And last but not least, reducers tie states and actions to together.
>   It’s just a pure function with a switch statement that checks the
>   action type and return new state of the app. In our article example,
>   the reducer looks like this:

Here, notice the statement **return new state of the app**

To explain this, they showed/wrote this example

```
const initialState = {
  articlesById: null,
}
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ARTICLES_FETCHED:
      return {
        ...state,
        articlesById: action.articlesById
      }
    default:
      return initialState
  }
}
```

**[Question]** Here, I am unable to figure out how it is returning the new state of the app. For all i can see is that it is returning new object having previous state and something which is articles by ID. So firstly can someone please explain the statement?

Secondly, what do they mean when they did this in the code above

```
articlesById: action.articlesById
```

Considering this to be our redux store (from the article) i.e I can't see  `action.articlesById` anywhere the  redux store.

Ps: This our redux store from the blog post (c[lick here to go through the article](https://blog.cloudboost.io/beginners-guide-to-react-redux-painting-a-mental-model-ed0279d55836))

```
{ type: 'ARTICLES_FETCHED', 
  payload: [{
      "id": 314,
      "title": "6 innovative apps utilizing the ethereum network",
      "source": "Investopedia‎",
      "link": "http://www.investopedia.com/news/6-innovative...",
      "date": "1500523200",
      "type": "msm"
    },
    {
      "id": 893,
      "title": "what is plasma and how will it strengthen...",
      "source": "Investopedia‎",
      "link": "http://www.investopedia.com/news/what-plasma-and...",
      "date": "1502856000",
      "type": "msm"
    },..] 
}
```

Comment: It returns an updated state with the changes depending on the action. A new object is generated to easily detect changes.

Comment: you need to dispatch an action after fetching the actual articles, with something like this, before the reducer will receive the articles: `{ type: types.ARTICLES_FETCHED, articlesById: [ /* articles in here */ ] }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Question] Here, I am unable to figure out how it is returning the new state of the app. For all i can see is that **it is returning new objec**t having previous state and something which is articles by ID. So firstly can someone please explain the statement?

**[Answer]** You return a new Object, that's right. It means that you don't manipulate directly the state (don't mutate state), instead you return a new state (object). 
This is a concept of functional programming, is called pure functions, and is one of the key concepts of Redux.

As the docs explains: "Reducers are just pure functions that take the previous state and an action, and return the next state"

Check here: [Changes are made with pure functions](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions)

Edit: About your **2nd question**. See the comments for explanations:

```
const initialState = {
  articlesById: null,
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // If the action type is ARTICLES_FETCHED, you return a new state
    case types.ARTICLES_FETCHED: 
      // You are returning a new object created wit literal syntax `{}`
      return {
        ...state, // You are using the spread operator `...` to get all the properties of `state`
        articlesById: action.articlesById // You are setting the property `articlesById` of the new object to the property `articlesById` of your action (if defined)
      }
    default: // If the action type is not ARTICLES_FETCHED, then you return the initial state without any change
      return state; // I've made a change here, you can just return `state`, because your state has the default value of initialState
  }
}
```

Comment: In the above example, we didn't mutated the state just returned the new object? Also if you can please answer explain the second part of question as well :)